# Make warning "makes pointer from integer without a cast" as error

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I'm trying to make the warning " warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ makes pointer from integer without a cast" as an error, but can't find the name of the option.

I've tried all warnings from

```
gcc -Q --help=warnings | grep enabled
```

Tried to either do -Werror=XXXX and name of the option from the list,

or even tried to disable warning -Wno-XXXX, and couldn't disable.

Does anybody know option for this particular warning?

Comment: Time to switch to clang!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to know it as well, so I checked the gcc source (4.8.1). In c-typeck.c there is the following code that emits the warning:

```
    WARN_FOR_ASSIGNMENT (location, 0,
                         G_("passing argument %d of %qE makes "
                            "pointer from integer without a cast"),
                         G_("assignment makes pointer from integer "
                            "without a cast"),
                         G_("initialization makes pointer from "
                            "integer without a cast"),
                         G_("return makes pointer from integer "
                            "without a cast"));
```

See the `0` second argument to `WAIT_FOR_ASSIGNMENT`? Normally, that is the flag for one of the diagnostic options. In this case it is zero, however, so I'm afraid that this means that the error cannot be specifically made an error.

Answer (score 0):

As the gcc Manual states

> -Werror= Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended, for example -Werror=switch turns the warnings
>   controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form,
>   to be used to negate -Werror for specific warnings, for example
>   -Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect. You can use the -fdiagnostics-show-option option to have each controllable warning amended with the option which
>   controls it, to determine what to use with this option.

any supported option should be reported by using the -fdiagnostics-show-option switch.

If you are lucky your gcc version might give you the possibility to selectivly turn your warning into an error. 
The version I am using definitely doesn't, so either using

> -Werror
>       Make all warnings into errors.

or

> -pedantic-errors
>       Like -pedantic, except that errors are produced rather than warnings.

might be the only possibilities to have gcc emit an error.